# supertype initiallzation is impossible without primary constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

I want create a adapter extend BaseAdapter,like this:

```
        class TestAdapter: BaseAdapter() {
            var mData:LinkedList<String>?=null
            var mContext:Context?=null

            constructor(mData: LinkedList<String>?, mContext: Context?) : super() {
                this.mData = mData
                this.mContext = mContext
            }
           Blablabla…….
        }
```

But AS give me a error message:supertype initiallzation is impossible without primary constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you only want `TestAdapter` to have one constructor (the one with the parameters), right?  If so, you should re-write it and put the parameters as part of the class declaration rather than using a separate `constructor`, like this:

`class TestAdapter(mData: LinkedList<String>?, mContext: Context?) : BaseAdapter()`

If, conversely, you want `TestAdapter` to have two constructors (one with no parameters and one with parameters), then you need to do it as follows:

```
class TestAdapter() : BaseAdapter() {
    constructor(mData: LinkedList<String>?, mContext: Context?) : this() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this() instead of super().Because BaseAdapter() already extends in class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import java.util.*

class TestActivity() : BaseAdapter() {

 var mData: LinkedList<String>?=null
 var mContext: Context?=null

constructor(mData: LinkedList<String>?, mContext: Context?) : this() {
this.mData = mData
this.mContext = mContext
}

 }
```

Comment: Error message: No value passed for parameter ‘xxxxx'